# There is no textWatcher or setError method on third party editText library

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am working on one app in that I use floatable hint edittext library. That librery is

implementation 'com.github.thomhurst:ExpandableHintText:1.0.7'
link :- https://github.com/thomhurst/ExpandableHintText

But in that in didn't access some functions such as setError(), addOnTextChangeListner() etc.
Now what can I do I can't get any solution. I can't change the library cause my app ui is depended on this.

Thanks is advance for answering.

Comment: you haven't really asked a question yet though, if that library doesn't allow you to do that, then you can't do it

Comment: so what can i now

Comment: you can use the standard material textinput layouts android provides, you can clone that library and build all the functionality you need yourself, or you can ask the author of the library for help

Comment: is there any alternate of textWatcher for live editText changed data

Comment: @Hiten It might be possible to use the underlying `EditText` and set the error, text watcher etc. on it. See my answer below.

Comment: @Hiten Did my answer help?

Comment: Thanks Gergely for your efforts, but still it not works.

Comment: @Hiten What doesn't work exactly?

Answer (score 2):

While the `ExpandableHintText` widget itself has no methods for setting error or text watchers, the underlying `EditText` can be used by the [`useEditText`](https://github.com/thomhurst/ExpandableHintText/blob/master/expandablehinttext/src/main/java/com/tomlonghurst/expandablehinttext/ExpandableHintText.kt#L47) method.

Here's an example of using this to set the error:

```kotlin
yourHintTextWidget.useEditText { editText -> editText.error = "Very wrong, so error, wow" }
```

> Note that I haven't tested this, I've just found it in the source.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because the developer of that library has created the ExpandableTextHint extending from Frame Layout, you can check out this

https://github.com/thomhurst/ExpandableHintText/blob/master/expandablehinttext/src/main/java/com/tomlonghurst/expandablehinttext/ExpandableHintText.kt.

So What you can do is to use Material Text Input Layout like this,

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputFirstName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textInputLabelTextColor"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:errorIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_error"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/textInputLabelTextColor"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userProfilePhoto"
        app:shapeAppearance="?attr/shapeAppearanceSmallComponent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/inputName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:maxLength="25"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:textColor="@color/textInputTextColor" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I know this is a lot of code as compared to that library but it's definitely worth it.

Also you can customise this further more check out this official documentation.

https://material.io/components/text-fields/android